# Difference between XML Schema and XMI

Tags: xml, xsd, xmi

What is the difference between XML Schema (XSD) and XMI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit like the difference between a dictionary and a gardening catalogue. In other words, they have very little in common.

XML Schema is a way of describing the structure and constraints on a class of XML documents.

XMI is an XML representation of UML models.

If you don't understand the difference, then you haven't understood one of these specifications, or perhaps you haven't understood either of them.

Comment: My problem is the following: When I look at XSD it defines my model in a XML based way. And when I look at a XMI file, it also defines the model in a XML based way. So I don't understand why I need to formats. Wouldn't XMI or XSD be enough ?!

Comment: The XSD does not define the model - it defines the structure of the XML - it can happen that the structure of the XML correspond in some way to your data model, but they are two different things.

Comment: XMI might tell you that a book can have multiple authors and authors can write multiple books. It doesn't tell you how the relationship between books and authors is represented in an XML document.

Comment: BPMN 2.0 provides both an XMI and XSD-based serialization: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-3076. Therefore, XMI is not always a representation of UML models.

Comment: This is actually a very sensible question, and this answer is glossing over the complexity of XMI. For an interesting exposition, see this presentation: [Introduction to XML Metadata Interchange](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/f/f0/OMCW_chapter04_IntroductionToXMI.SINTEF.pdf).

Comment: I also recommend reading [Mastering XMI: Java Programming with XMI, XML and UML](https://www.wiley.com/en-am/Mastering+XMI%3A+Java+Programming+with+XMI%2C+XML+and+UML-p-9780471384298) - chapters "XMI: Representing Objects in XML" and "Related Standards: XML and UML" to gain a better understanding of how meta-models and XML Schemas (XSDs) are related to each other.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for posting in this super-old thread, but I just came around the same problem and found that the accepted answer is super-wrong, which is curious because the author of the accepted answer apparently has not understood anything about XMI or XMI radically changed in the recent past.

XMI 2.5.1 is in fact a standard that describes how to create an XML Schema from a given MOF model and how to implement cross-references between objects as XML only allows hierarchical structures.

Thus, XMI can be applied to any domain, not just software modeling (UML) or business processes (BPMN). However, be careful that XMI is usually applied at the level of a metamodel, not the level of an instance model.

Comment: Excellent answer, should be the accepted response.